# How to use edebug on a function

Tags: debugging, edebug

I am trying to debug a [problem with the `alert.el` package](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert/issues/47#) using `edebug`.  However, I am unable to step through the `alert` function.

I expect the debugger to enter the function and allow me to step through.  Instead, it terminates.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Open an Emacs instance opened with `emacs -Q`
2. Evaluate `(package-initialize)`
3. Call `C-u C-M-x` on `(alert "Hello, world!")`

At this point, I see an indicator in my fringe.

[image: On the fringe]

4. Press `i` to step into the function call

On pressing `i`, I quickly see "Go..." printed to the minibuffer and the fringe indicator disappears.

I am no longer debugging.

---

Checking `C-h f alert` shows me that it is an autoloaded function.  *Might this be affecting my ability to step into it?*

I have tried toggling `(debug-on-error)` and stepping through with `d`.  However, I can't see the source code while stepping.  Whenever I try to open another buffer with the source code in it, pressing `d` in the `*Backtrace*` closes the source code buffer.  *Is there a way to use `(debug-on-error)` and see the source code while stepping through execution?*

Any advice you have for debugging is welcome.

Comment: You can explicitly load `alert.el` with `load-library` or `require`.

Comment: That was something I tried, running `(require 'alert)` after Step 2.  When I did that, I experienced the same behavior with `edebug`.  I did notice however that the help description changes to say `"alert is an autoloaded Lisp closure..."`.  Might that affect `edebug`'s behavior?  I noticed this line in the documentation: "Most Emacs Lisp programs, however, should not interact directly with lexical environments in this way; only specialized programs like debuggers."  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html#Lexical-Binding

Comment: Step 3 i s wrong: you need to do `C-u C-M-x` on the *definition* of the alert function, not on its use.

Comment: @NickD, I think you answered this question, which seems to have really been about the use of the `eval-defun` or `edebug-eval-defun`.  It so happens that the definition of `alert` is simply `(defgroup alert nil :group 'emacs)`.  I have questions about how to debug this, but that's probably better suited for a separate question.  I'll polish up this post to better reflect the question it's asking.  You post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: That's not true: there is a customization *group* called `alert` and there is a *function* called `alert`: go to line 1022 of `alert.el` to see it. It's the latter that you want to apply `C-u C-M-x` to.

Comment: Strange xref-find-definition brings you to the defgroup but should prolly take you to `(cl-defun alert ...` at line 1023. If you debug the cl-defun it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `C-u C-M-x` on the *definition* of a function in order to enable edebug to instrument it for debugging. Your step 3. applies it to the *use* of the function, which does not do anything useful.

Download the [alert.el](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwiegley/alert/master/alert.el) file and load it with e.g. `(load-file "/path/to/alert.el")`, then open the file in emacs and navigate to the definition of the alert *function* on line 1022 or thereabouts. That's where you want to do `C-u C-M-x`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a framework like doom emacs `C-u C-M-x` is `edebug-defun` and it doesn't have any keybinding by default (using edebug in doom emacs isn't documented at all as a matter of fact so you are on your own when trying to debug emacs lisp).